# kafka-connect Error: Unable to obtain valid replication slot

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, database-replication

The Kafka debezium-postgres connector in my application is throwing this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to obtain valid replication slot. Make sure there are no long-running transactions running in parallel as they may hinder the allocation of the replication slot when starting this connector
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.readReplicationSlotInfo(PostgresConnection.java:226)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.getReplicationSlotState(PostgresConnection.java:150)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:98)
    at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The application uses postgresql version 9.6.11, the value of `max_replication_slots` is 10. I can see the active logical replication_slot in the database with confirmed_flush_lsn = null, restart_lsn = 3/93043310, catalog_xmin = 202656, active = t, datoid = 16407, slot_type = logical, active_pid = 32183, plugin = wal2json, slot_name = slot1, database = db1 (I have replaced the slot name and db names with dummy values)
As per my understanding since confirmed_flush_lsn = null for a logical replication slot in here is causing this error as it's preventing the connector to find this slot.

How can I fix this and why would confirmed_flush_lsn value will be null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed by rebooting the rds DB instance in aws which was referred by the connector , After that the value of confirmed_flush_lsn got reset to a non-null value somewhat similar to (restart_lsn  = 3/93043310). The kafka-connect was able to find the replication_slot "slot1" as expected. The connectors were also up.
This fixed my problem temporarily but still I would like to understand what set confirmed_flush_lsn =null for a logical replication_slot in the first place.